# How to find the process id folder for a process in Android using adb shell

Tags: android, adb

Every new process which gets created is supposed to get a folder in /proc
so if I launch an app on my android phone lets say  a game how do I find its corresponding folder in /proc using adb shell
when I list out the folders using ls /proc how do I know which folder corresponds to the app

Answer (score 0):

Try out the name of the application

for example if you launch an app by the name of gunship battle
use the following command
ps | grep -w "gunship"

where ps lists the running processes which is piped into grep using '|' symbol
and grep finds the line containing the word  gunship
and displays an output something like

```
u0_a521   29310 607   1686420 125304 SyS_epoll_ 0000000000 S com.mobile.gunship
```

where 29310 is the PID for the process which is the corresponding folder listed in ls /proc

after that, you can use ls /proc/[PID] i.e. ls/proc/29310 to get more info on the process